# Bison Fatal error

Tags: bison

```
%union {char *str; tree_t *t;}
%token<str> floating dig dig1 var cmnt path path1 web ERROR
%token equal lbrack rbrack semicolon rbrack1 newline newline1 creturn quote bkslash  bkslash2 bkslashq global host
%type<t> globalrule openrule hostrule openrule1 keyrule valuerule

%start globalrule
%%

globalrule: 

     global openrule { cur->next = (tree_t *)malloc(sizeof(tree_t));  cur=cur->next;   cur->var_id= "";cur->var_name="GLOBAL"; cur->var_value="";cur->next=0; };

   | newline globalrule {};

   | cmnt globalrule {};


openrule:

     lbrack keyrule { };

   | lbrack newline keyrule {cur->next = (tree_t *)malloc(sizeof(tree_t));  cur=cur->next;   cur->var_id= "";cur->var_name="GLOBAL"; cur->var_value="";cur->next=0;};

   | lbrack newline newline keyrule { cur->next = (tree_t *)malloc(sizeof(tree_t));  cur=cur->next;   cur->var_id= "";cur->var_name="GLOBAL"; cur->var_value="";cur->next=0;};

   | lbrack newline newline newline keyrule { cur->next = (tree_t *)malloc(sizeof(tree_t));  cur=cur->next;   cur->var_id= "";cur->var_name="GLOBAL"; cur->var_value="";cur->next=0; };

   | cmnt openrule {};

   | newline openrule {};
```

I get the fatal error:

```
bison -d grammar.y
grammar.y: warning: 7 nonterminals useless in grammar
grammar.y: warning: 30 rules useless in grammar
grammar.y:18.8-17: fatal error: start symbol globalrule does not derive any sentence
make: *** [grammar.tab.o] Error 1
```

I dont understand what is wrong. I have seen the previous post where someoone had a missing "|". But mine seems correct.

Answer (score 2):

`globalrule` is unsatisfiable because all of its productions are recursive. So any expansion of `globalrule` needs to include itself. That's impossible, so `bison` discards all the productions of `globalrule` and then correctly notes that no other rule is reachable.

Also, don't put semicolons at the end of every alternative; you should only put a semicolon at the end of the last alternative for a non-terminal (and even then, it's optional, but useful for readers).

Finally, I have no idea what you are attempting to do, but it is usual to ignore comments in the lexer rather than pushing them up to the parser, since that either complicates the grammar or restricts the places where comments can go, or both.